# Different meanings in context - "having thus deeply committed himself" - but the question is, committed to what?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Background: In Chapter 18 of Dickens' Great Expectations, Mr Wopsle was reading aloud a sensational murder case from the newspaper; even though it was only a preliminary report, before the trial had even begun, Mr Wopsle got carried away in his own dramatization and eventually concluded it was 'Wilful Murder', and the man, Guilty. Mr Jaggers (a criminal defence lawyer) then spoke up and pointed out that the defendant had not pleaded guilty, and proceeded to make an example of Mr Wopsle.

Q: In the passage below, does the phrase "having thus deeply committed himself" point to his commitment to serve on the jury or his commitment to the conclusion of Guilty that he has drawn? (I've given a couple of lead-in paragraphs to give context, as possible reference for the "thus" of the phrase in question.)

> "Yes," repeated [Mr Jaggers], looking round at the rest of the company with his right hand extended towards the witness, Wopsle. "And now I ask you what you say to the conscience of that man who, with that passage before his eyes, can lay his head upon his pillow after having pronounced a fellow-creature guilty, unheard?"
>
> We all began to suspect that Mr. Wopsle was not the man we had thought him, and that he was beginning to be found out.
>
> "And that same man, remember," pursued the gentleman, throwing his finger at Mr. Wopsle heavily,--"that same man might be summoned as a juryman upon this very trial, and, having thus deeply committed himself, might return to the bosom of his family and lay his head upon his pillow, after deliberately swearing that he would well and truly try the issue joined between Our Sovereign Lord the King and the prisoner at the bar, and would a true verdict give according to the evidence, so help him God!"

As always, thank you!